# SqlPlus (Oracle) Spool Formatting Issue

Tags: oracle, email, format, sqlplus, spool

I have scheduled a shell script which is outputting the following email. I want to remove the unwanted/additional duplicated text which is being printed using the `dual` table below to give a heading to my SQL select output.

How can I do it?

Following is the spool SQL script. After the script execution is done (`/home/oracle/MFS_ALERT/PGW_ALERTS_FRAUDS/PGW_ALERTS.out`) file is added to the email body and sent to recipients.

Can you guide which set parameter command is missing OR which one is extra or unnecessary below?

**This is shell script file code.**

```
sqlplus user/pass@pgwdb @/home/oracle/MFS_ALERT/PGW_ALERTS_FRAUDS/PGW_ALERTS.sql
sleep 5
/bin/mail -s "MFS PGW Fraud Alerts (Day)" -r “test-email-1@email-domain.com” "test-email-2@email-domain.com" < /home/oracle/MFS_ALERT/PGW_ALERTS_FRAUDS/PGW_ALERTS.out
```

### **PGW_ALERTS.sql   Code**

```
set echo off;
set feedback off ; 
set verify off ;
set serveroutput off;
set heading on;
set trimspool on;
set headsep off;
set PAGESIZE 60;
set LINESIZE 400;
SET WRAP OFF;
SET COLSEP '    ';
set numw 20;

SPOOL /home/oracle/MFS_ALERT/PGW_ALERTS_FRAUDS/PGW_ALERTS.out append;

select '======  Transactions with count > 2 from same MSISDN  ======' from dual;

SELECT '"'
  || MOBILENUMBER
  || '"' MSISDN,
  AMOUNT/100 AMOUNT,
  DECODE(TXNTYPEID,'6','MW', '0') TXN_TYPE,
  MERCHANTCODE,
  COUNT (*) COUNT
FROM TBL_TXN_LOG
WHERE TXNTYPEID ='6'
AND AMOUNT     <=10000
AND TXNDATETIME>= SYSDATE -1
AND STATUS      ='xxxx'
GROUP BY '"'
  || MOBILENUMBER
  || '"', AMOUNT/100, DECODE(TXNTYPEID,'6','MW', '0'), MERCHANTCODE
HAVING COUNT (*) > 2
UNION ALL
SELECT '"'
  || MOBILENUMBER
  || '"' MSISDN ,
  AMOUNT/100 AMOUNT,
  DECODE(TXNTYPEID,'164', 'Card', '0') TXN_TYPE,
  MERCHANTCODE,
  COUNT (*) COUNT
FROM TBL_TXN_LOG
WHERE TXNTYPEID ='164'
AND AMOUNT     >=2500000
AND TXNDATETIME>= SYSDATE - 1
AND STATUS      ='xxxx'
GROUP BY MOBILENUMBER,
  AMOUNT,
  DECODE(TXNTYPEID,'164','Card', '0') ,
  MERCHANTCODE
HAVING COUNT (*) > 1 
;

SPOOL OFF;

SET DEFINE ON
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
quit
```

**The email which recipient is getting.,**

> -----Original Message----- From: destination.email@emaildomain.com Sent: Friday, December 8, 2017 7:36 PM To:
> destination.email@emaildomain.com Subject: MFS PGW Fraud Alerts (4
> Hourly)
>
> ***> '======TRANSACTIONSWITHAMOUNT<100FORMW&>25000======'
>
> > --------------------------------------------------------------***
>
> ======  Transactions with Amount < 100 for MW & > 25000 ======
>
> MSISDN                                  AMOUNT    TXN_    MERCHANTCODE
> COUNT
> ----------------------    --------------------    ----    ------------------------------    -------------------- "924008482888"                               70    MW      00342386                                             1
> "924008345433"                               20    MW      002218387
> 1

---

I want to remove these extra lines

> '======TRANSACTIONSWITHAMOUNT<100FORMW&>25000======'
>
> ---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query a bit, use an alias for your heading, and turn off/on heading as shown:

```
set heading off
select '======  Transactions with count > 2 from same MSISDN  ======' as info from dual;

select '<pre>' from dual;
set heading on
-- rest of your query
set heading off
select '</pre>' from dual;
```

That should do the trick if the message is being sent in HTML format.

Comment: The email body is plain text and not html. I believe <pre> tag wont work for sure.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot.
Someone may please select Mark's answer as the correct answer please.